# Listing Postgres databases in Python

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I have to get the names of Postgres databases in Python. How do I do that? I need to be able to put these names into a list.

Comment: `select datname from pg_database`?

Comment: @a_hosre_with_no_name is there a way of executing it in python without secifying a database in the connection string?

Comment: No, you always need to connect to _some_ database

Answer (score -1):

you can use `pg_dumpall` and psql as superuser

```
pg_dumpall -h localhost -U postgres -f pg_dumpall.sql
```

Comment: As far as I get it, this command will create a file containing info about databases. Is there a good way of implementing it into python?

Comment: You would need to connect your databases first - for example using psycopg package, then create a function to run queries in bash script